# FME API Module null?

Tags: python, esri-geodatabase, convert, fme-form

I try to convert my geodatabase to Excel.
And i have a strange message:

> FME API version of module 'XLS_ADO'
>   matches current internal version (3.6
>   20101014) Trying to find a DYNAMIC
>   plugin for reader named `NULL' Loaded
>   module 'NULL' from file
>   'C:\apps\FME\plugins/NULL.dll' FME API
>   version of module 'NULL' matches
>   current internal version (3.6
>   20101014) FME API version of module
>   'XLS_ADO' matches current internal
>   version (3.6 20101014) FME API version
>   of module 'XLS_ADO' matches current
>   internal version (3.6 20101014) MS
>   Excel Writer: Opening`null' for write
>   operation MS Excel Writer: Connection
>   failed.  Connection string
>   `Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data
>   Source=null;Extended Properties="Excel
>   8.0;HDR=YES"'. Provider error`La table externe n'est pas dans le format
>   attendu.' Failed to open writer

The table is not in the expected format.

An idea ?
Thanks

Comment: What does 'La table externe n'est pas dans le format attendu.' mean? Anyways, I think this happens when it can't find either the database (.xls OR .xlsx file) or the table (worksheet within the .xls or .xlsx file).

Comment: "Provider error from external table not in expected format"

Comment: A solution for me ?

Answer (score 2):

The NULL module messages are a red herring.  I believe the destination dataset has not been specified (a Python null passed instead?).

> MS Excel Writer: Opening '**null**' for write operation
>
> MS Excel Writer: Connection failed. Connection string Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=**null**;Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;HDR=YES"'.

Specifying the path to the Excel file you wish to write to will probably resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The real problem is MS Excel Writer: Failed to write a feature of type `feature' to the database. 
Provider error`Excel Table is full.'.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: .xls format worksheets can only hold up to 65,536 rows, while .xlsx format worksheets can hold up to 1,048,576 rows. Check that these are not being exceeded.